# Getting started with arduino, on linux

Tags: linux, unix, arduino

I would like to get started with programming on arduino, and am considering buying this kit https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11930 but I'm concerned about not being able to run this on linux.

I still don't know much about arduino, but could I still run this properly, and still be able to follow the programs without some obvious linux/windows differences?

Also, if anyone has any other reccomendations for some others kits to people new to arduino programming, but not new to programming, I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arduino IDE itself runs fine under Linux (as well as Java programs can), and the compiler works perfectly (it uses GCC under the hood). If you're using a serial connection then it changes from `COMxx` to `/dev/ttyNNNxx` (e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0` [although I haven't actually seen it yet since I use a ISP programmer, but it *should* look something like that]). Also, no extra drivers needed. However, whether you're using a serial connection or a ISP programmer, you'll want to add a udev rule so that user access to the device is allowed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can install arduino on Ubuntu with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arduino arduino-core
```

Is this something you are looking for ?

Comment: I'm on arch linux, so I believe it's `yaourt arduino`, but I was more concerned that the kit would come with some windows programs, that I couldn't run on linux that would make the kit completely useless.